# Jquery.multiSelect() Sin entrar en el jquery.validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

¿Cómo podría hacer que al hacer la llamada a `multiSelect('deselect_all')` o `multiSelect('select_all')` No entre en el `jquery.validate`?

Un pequeño ejemplo, en un listado dentro del contenedor con id="motivo" ej:

```
<select multiple="multiple"  id="motivo">
<div class="ms-selectable"><ul class="ms-list" tabindex="-1"><li class="ms-    
optgroup-container" id="optgroup-selectable-762866512">
<ul class="ms-optgroup">
<li class="ms-optgroup-label"><span> 1 - Capacidad visual</span></li>
<li class="ms-elem-selectable" id="36598990-selectable"><span> 1. 1 - 
Agudeza visual</span></li>
<li class="ms-elem-selectable" id="36598991-selectable"><span> 1. 2 - Campo 
visual</span></li>
<li selected="selected" class="ms-elem-selectable ms-selected" id="36598992-
selectable" style="display: none;"><span> 1. 3 - Afaquias y 
pseudoafaquias</span></li></ul></div>
```

Luego tenemos un botón que ejecuta el `multiSelect`:

```
$('#motivo').multiSelect('select_all');
```

Cuando se ejecuta el `multiSelect` de `Jquery.Multi-Select.js` lanza despues el `jquery.validate.js`

Comment: Por favor, crea un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema y cómo se dispara jQuery.validate cuando haces uso de multiSelect.

Comment: El código agregado no corresponde a un [mcve] falta el jQuery y la carga de las librerías involucradas.